# Resource Scheduling App + Google Calendar

Tags: calendar

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I even need to Google for this one.

We need to replace a calendar app that was written eons ago for our moving company. The app took down the address and basic information, as well as scheduled a time and most importantly, the resources involved in the move. The manager of our moving company is very reluctant to move away from the old app, as she likes having the address and resources visible at a glance from the calendar itself.

So what I'm looking for is:

- A calendar that syncs/integrates with Google Calendar
- Allows for scheduling resources
- Provides a summary at a glance

Google Calendar itself *almost* works, but it falls short at the summary, setting up the resources is a little clunky (requires admin access), and I don't think the UI will be sufficient for the users (they'll get confused).

[image]

So I don't think that's going to fly.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The manager is reluctant to move away, why move away? What is wrong with the old app? At the end of the day, will the new app simply be the same as the old app?

Comment: @JamesTikalsky The old app was custom built on top of IBM Domino. :) We've switched to Google Apps, and that server is going away soon. Not going to pay the license/support just because one of our managers wants their old calendar app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Sunrise Calendar](https://calendar.sunrise.am/). I use it on all my devices (iPad + Laptop) and it was also specifically made for Google Calendar too.

The benefits are...

- Can use a web interface if you want (If on chrome you can use their extension version which allows offline access too)
- Can integrate/add multiple accounts including Google and integrates with Google Calendar
- Can be used on multiple platforms including iPhone, iPad, Google Chrome ect
- Has a really good user interface I have noticed
- Really easy to use
- Free of course

Snapshots of what it looks like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Negatives...

- I can't say there are no negatives because everything has a plus side and a down side to it but perhaps the only downside I can think of is you can't integrate Exchange calendar yet

Supported accounts though are....

- Google Calendar
- iCloud
- Facebook
- Foursquare
- Twitter
- Linkedin
- Producteev
- Evernote
- GitHub
- Songkick
- Asana and TripIt

Comment: Nice! Thanks. Manager felt a lot better looking at that versus the standard Google Calendar interface.

Comment: I'm glad I could help @Tanner. :)

Comment: And Now Trello and Todoist as well!

Comment: The link you gave is now dead.  It appears that sunrise calendar is also dead: http://blog.sunrise.am/

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [ClipPod](http://clippod.com). ClipPod adds shared notes and attachments to your Google Calendar events, essentially converting your Calendar into a basic resource scheduling / project management app.

[image]

Comment: Does it provide a "summary at a glance", as the OP states in his requirements?

Comment: I couldn't grasp how this could be remotely useful for me.

Comment: Here are a few use cases - https://clippod.com/use-cases